# How to specify different bindingMode for in and out queries?

Tags: java, json, rest, apache-camel, marshalling

I'm using camel-swagger and writing a REST Api.

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    // configure we want to use servlet as the component for the rest DSL
    // and we enable json binding mode
    restConfiguration().component("netty4-http")
            // use json binding mode so Camel automatic binds json <--> pojo
            .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto)
            // and output using pretty print
            .dataFormatProperty("prettyPrint", "true")
            .dataFormatProperty("json.in.disableFeatures", "FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES")
            // setup context path on localhost and port number that netty will use
            .port("{{env:HTTP_PORT:8080}}")
            // add swagger api-doc out of the box
            .apiContextPath("/swagger.json")
            .apiProperty("api.title", "HtmlCleaner")
            .apiProperty("api.version", "1.0")
            .apiProperty("api.description", "HtmlCleaner")
            // and enable CORS
            .apiProperty("cors", "true")
            .enableCORS(true);


    rest("/htmlcleaner").description("HtmlCleaner")
            .consumes("text/plain").produces("application/json")


    .post().description("Extract text content from HTML").type(String.class)
            .to("bean:HtmlCleaner?method=getTextFromHtml").outType(TextDocument.class);
}
```

I got a problem with the `bindingMode` because the input type is just a String and the output type is a POJO which should be marshalled to json.

If i set `bindingMode` to off, the input is ok (text/plain which is received as a String) but obviously my POJO isn't marshalled to json when returning the response.

If is set `bindingMode` to json, the input query transformation throws an exception.

In the camel-restdsl documentation :

> From Camel 2.16.3 onwards the binding from POJO to JSon/JAXB will only >happen if the content-type header includes the word json or xml >representatively. This allows you to specify a custom content-type if the >message body should not attempt to be marshalled using the binding. For >example if the message body is a custom binary payload etc.

Unfortunately it seems that even when sending content-type as text/plain, the component is still trying to marshall. (I'm using camel 2.18.0)

EDIT: Actually, I did misread the documentation, this feature is working on output (POJO->JSON), my problem is I want to desactivate marshalling for input...

I tried to add a route to transform my POJO to json before returning the response to user, but I'm receiving a NettyStream body instead of my POJO type.

Any ideas ?